# Delete the filtered data

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I want to remove the filtered data using VBA code where the sheet has header(which should not be deleted) and the end is unknown.

I tried as below

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
```

but it also removing the header. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Have a look e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26930011/delete-rows-from-table-if-entries-duplicate-another-table-in-excel-using-vba/26934740#26934740

Comment: but it is different scenario. I asked to remove the filtered data after header.

Comment: That did what you want when I ran it.  Is something else happening in your code that isn't shown here?

Comment: Make sure your Range doesn't include the header row?

Comment: Check the range address first `MsgBox ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Address`. If it returns the correct address, there is no reason for your code not to work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a DBExtract sheet which has header and filtered values. To remove the filtered values data. Please check with below example. That will keep your header and will remove the filtered records only.

**Note  while you select your range**

Select your range as Maximum when you are not aware of the range. That's why I kept it as BF99999 ( BF is the last column that contains data and 99999.. you can chose max value.

```
  Sub DeleteFilteredData()

             Dim DbExtract As Worksheet
             Set DbExtract = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Export Worksheet")
             DbExtract.Range("A2:BF9999").SpecialCell(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete

    End Sub
```