# VBA: Speed efficient deleting rows

Tags: vba, excel, delete-row, processing-efficiency

My solution takes a long time to execute. I have file with 60k rows, and it can be bigger.  Can you help me to make this process faster?

```
Sub kary()

Dim table As Variant
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim liczba, i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set Wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook

table = Wb.Worksheets("raport").Range("A1").CurrentRegion

i = 8
While Cells(i, 1) <> ""
    If Cells(i, 11) <= 0 Or Cells(i, 5) = "FV_K" Or Cells(i, 5) = "KFD" Or Cells(i, 5) = "KR" Then
        Rows(i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Else
        i = i + 1
    End If
Wend

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Have a look e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26934740/863240).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can try setting calculation to manual and disabling events

```
'Optimise code performance
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
     .
     .
     .

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
```